# My Crypter Code Written in VB.NET has two Errors that I don't know how to solve?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have some code that I wrote for a simple Crypter in VB.ET 2010 Express Edition. I tried to build it, and I get two Errors that I don't know how to fix. 
Here is the Code

```
Public Class MainWindow 'Class Name
Dim infectedfile, stub As String

Private Property Cryptfile As String

Private Sub MainWindow_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub
```

The Error I get is "Event 'Load' cannot be found"
And here is the second line of code:

```
Dim btSalt() As Byte = New Byte() (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

The Error I get is "Bounds can be specified only for the Top-Level array when initializing an array of arrays."

All help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your 2nd error, you should declare your array like this:

```
Dim btSalt() As Byte = New Byte() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

As for the first error, we'll need more context.

Cheers

EDIT:

Here's how to override the OnLoad method, which is prefered over subscribing to own event, ie form events:

```
Public Class Form1

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
          MyBase.OnLoad(e)

        'Put your code here, code that you would have placed in your event handler
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Ok, first, I never subscribe to form events in the form itself. I always prefer overriding the OnXXXX method instead. I'll post some code in my answer in a bit.

Comment: Thanks for this, and I updated my question to provide more information about error 1.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answered if it answered your questions